# Viewing pdf file from server inside webview in desktop Mac

Tags: macos, cocoa

Hi Newbie question here,

I'm trying to use webview to load up a pdf file from a webserver.

is this something that webview can do?

as when I send in the URL via the below method

```
NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com/mypdffile.pdf"];
NSURLRequest*request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[_webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
```

all I get is a screen with initialsing.. on it..

sending a normal URL to www.google.com  works fine.

so is this something webview can't do?

Please point me in the right direction.

thank you